# I am trying to do a Membership Import from a spreadsheet (.csv file). All imports fail with the message "No matching Contact found for (email add.)"

Tags: civimember, error, import

I am trying to do a Membership Import from a spreadsheet (Members.csv) with the following columnns:
Membership Type | MEMBERSHIP # | DATE OF PURCHASE | AMOUNT PAID | FIRST NAME | LAST NAME |   Mailing ADDRESS | POSTAL CODE | Summer Residence | Primary phone # | Secondary phone # | EMAIL | Topics of Interest | Notes | RECEIPT NUMBER

I created a 2nd spreadsheet to establish the contact data for each member (ContactList.csv) with the following columns:
FIRST NAME | LAST NAME | Primary phone # | Secondary phone # | EMAIL
with the same Email address as in the Members.csv file.  I added all these contacts using the Contacts > Import Contacts dialog and the ContactList.csv file.

I then tried the Memberships > Import Memberships dialog, using the Members.csv file.  On selecting "Import Now" I see the following:
[image]
On viewing the Import_Errors.csv file, I see all 47 rows of the table have the "Reason" as
"No matching Contact found for (email address)"
Why?  The same email address exists in the Contacts table.  How can I Import members if there is no way to establish a connection with the Contacts table?  I am missing something, but am unsure what.  We are running CiviCRM 5.64.3.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Brad Nickerson

Comment: What is your unsupervised dedupe matching rule (under Contacts > Find & Merge Duplicate Contacts)? Is it just email? Is it possible that you have more than one contact with the same email?

Comment: Your question says you are importing "MEMBERSHIP #" - how can you have this when you are importing them? If i understand right Memb ID won't exist. Is this possible confusion that your 'memb ID' should be your 'contact id'?

Comment: Hi Petednz.  The "MEMBERSHIP #" is already defined for members as part of our Excel based membership management system since 2019.  It is unclear what "Contact ID" means.  Assuming I first import the Contacts from the ContactsList.csv file, how do I then Export existing contacts so that it shows a Contact ID field?  I only have the FIRST NAME | LAST NAME | Primary phone # | Secondary phone # | EMAIL fields.  Is Contact ID an internal field defined by CiviCRM on import?  There is no "Export" option on the Contact main menu drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to LarsSG: having "Email (Unsupervised)" in "dedupe rules" works indeed.  Contact ID is required in case if all Dedupe Rules fail. In this case, first thing would be to Export existing contacts: not all PRIMARY fields, only Contact ID and Email. Then do some concatenating Excel magic ("vlookup" works too, thanks to peterdnz comment below) and Import results back.

Comment: You can definitely import contacts or memberships with email alone if your unsupervised dedupe rule only needs email.

Comment: @LarsSG Afraid your suggestion hasn't been working for me since 2017 ( including the last attempt made past week). Each time I start an import I hope an email or  an external id would suffice but it is always about contact id for existing contacts.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a specific issue, as this definitely does work in general. Have you tried what you're trying to do on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/?

Comment: vlookup is how i would add Contact ID to your membership import s'sheet but if you have a small / easy dataset then just ordering by email may suffice to copy in your contact ID

Comment: @LarsSG Thank you, will definitely try your approach the next import.

Comment: @LarsSG Hallelujah! It works w/o Contact ID, have just tried. Such a relief.